# matplotlib says image is too large when it's not

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm doing this plotting in Jupyter Notebook:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("{0} nodes".format(i*4))
print("put suptitle")

fig.text(0,0,s="error: {0}".format(errors[i-1]))
print("put text")

plt.plot(means, np.zeros(means.shape), "go")
print(means.shape)

plt.plot(patterns_test, outputs, "r.", label="outputs")
print(patterns_test.shape, outputs.shape)

plt.plot(patterns_test, targets_test, "b.", label="targets")
print(patterns_test.shape, targets_test.shape)

plt.legend()
print("legend")
```

I've printed the shape of everything that it plotted, and the values returned are:

```
put suptitle
put text
(16,)
(62,) (62,)
(62,) (62,)
legend
```

Clearly nothing is large. But here's the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    236 
    237     if 'png' in formats:
--> 238         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    239     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    240         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    120 
    121     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 122     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    123     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    124     if fmt == 'svg':

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2265                 orientation=orientation,
   2266                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2267                 **kwargs)
   2268         finally:
   2269             if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    505 
    506     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 507         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    508         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    509         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    420         Draw the figure using the renderer
    421         """
--> 422         self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)
    423         # acquire a lock on the shared font cache
    424         RendererAgg.lock.acquire()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in get_renderer(self, cleared)
    442 
    443         if need_new_renderer:
--> 444             self.renderer = RendererAgg(w, h, self.figure.dpi)
    445             self._lastKey = key
    446         elif cleared:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in __init__(self, width, height, dpi)
     90         self.width = width
     91         self.height = height
---> 92         self._renderer = _RendererAgg(int(width), int(height), dpi, debug=False)
     93         self._filter_renderers = []
     94 

ValueError: Image size of 298022x298 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1c139a84a8>
```

How can one sort this out?

Comment: Since we don't know, what any of the plotted variables contain, this question is probably difficult to answer without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I restarted Jupyter Notebook and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter Notebook you have *Kernel* -> *Restart*, try it first before restarting entire Jupyter Notebook. As well it may be caused by one of the other Jupyter tabs so *Kernel* -> *Restart* all the Jupyter tabs to release the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when my pyplot.legend() argument was too big.  A bug popped up and the list of legend items got really big.

There's not enough info in your question for anyone to reproduce your bug (or really diagnose it), but I'd suggest making sure that your legend is well behaved.